# How to clean project in android when below error is coming?

Tags: android

When clean my project and run it gives me console like,,,,,'

```
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] ERROR: Unknown command 'crunch'
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] Android Asset Packaging Tool
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] Usage:
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    resources        Print the resource table from the APK.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    configurations   Print the configurations in the APK.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    xmltree          Print the compiled xmls in the given assets.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    xmlstrings       Print the strings of the given compiled xml assets.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt p[ackage] [-d][-f][-m][-u][-v][-x][-z][-M AndroidManifest.xml] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [-0 extension [-0 extension ...]] [-g tolerance] [-j jarfile] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--debug-mode] [--min-sdk-version VAL] [--target-sdk-version VAL] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--app-version VAL] [--app-version-name TEXT] [--custom-package VAL] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--rename-manifest-package PACKAGE] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--rename-instrumentation-target-package PACKAGE] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--utf16] [--auto-add-overlay] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--max-res-version VAL] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [-I base-package [-I base-package ...]] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [-A asset-source-dir]  [-G class-list-file] [-P public-definitions-file] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [-S resource-sources [-S resource-sources ...]]         [-F apk-file] [-J R-file-dir] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--product product1,product2,...] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [raw-files-dir [raw-files-dir] ...]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    Package the android resources.  It will read assets and resources that are
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    supplied with the -M -A -S or raw-files-dir arguments.  The -J -P -F and -R
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    options control which files are output.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt r[emove] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    Delete specified files from Zip-compatible archive.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt a[dd] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    Add specified files to Zip-compatible archive.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt v[ersion]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    Print program version.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  Modifiers:
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -a  print Android-specific data (resources, manifest) when listing
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -c  specify which configurations to include.  The default is all
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        configurations.  The value of the parameter should be a comma
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        separated list of configuration values.  Locales should be specified
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        as either a language or language-region pair.  Some examples:
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]             en
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]             port,en
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]             port,land,en_US
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        If you put the special locale, zz_ZZ on the list, it will perform
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        pseudolocalization on the default locale, modifying all of the
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        strings so you can look for strings that missed the
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        internationalization process.  For example:
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]             port,land,zz_ZZ
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -d  one or more device assets to include, separated by commas
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -f  force overwrite of existing files
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -g  specify a pixel tolerance to force images to grayscale, default 0
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -j  specify a jar or zip file containing classes to include
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -k  junk path of file(s) added
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -m  make package directories under location specified by -J
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -u  update existing packages (add new, replace older, remove deleted files)
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -v  verbose output
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -x  create extending (non-application) resource IDs
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -z  require localization of resource attributes marked with
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        localization="suggested"
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -A  additional directory in which to find raw asset files
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -G  A file to output proguard options into.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -F  specify the apk file to output
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -I  add an existing package to base include set
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -J  specify where to output R.java resource constant definitions
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -M  specify full path to AndroidManifest.xml to include in zip
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -P  specify where to output public resource definitions
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will be scanned
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        and the first match found (left to right) will take precedence.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -0  specifies an additional extension for which such files will not
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        be stored compressed in the .apk.  An empty string means to not
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        compress any files at all.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --debug-mode
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:debuggable="true" in to the application node of the
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        manifest, making the application debuggable even on production devices.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --min-sdk-version
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:minSdkVersion in to manifest.  If the version is 7 or
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        higher, the default encoding for resources will be in UTF-8.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --target-sdk-version
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:targetSdkVersion in to manifest.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --max-res-version
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        ignores versioned resource directories above the given value.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --values
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        when used with "dump resources" also includes resource values.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --version-code
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:versionCode in to manifest.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --version-name
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:versionName in to manifest.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --custom-package
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        generates R.java into a different package.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --auto-add-overlay
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        Automatically add resources that are only in overlays.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --rename-manifest-package
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        Rewrite the manifest so that its package name is the package name
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        given here.  Relative class names (for example .Foo) will be
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        changed to absolute names with the old package so that the code
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        does not need to change.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --rename-instrumentation-target-package
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        Rewrite the manifest so that all of its instrumentation
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        components target the given package.  Useful when used in
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        conjunction with --rename-manifest-package to fix tests against
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        a package that has been renamed.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --product
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        Specifies which variant to choose for strings that have
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        product variants
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --utf16
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        changes default encoding for resources to UTF-16.  Only useful when API
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        level is set to 7 or higher where the default encoding is UTF-8.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] ERROR: Unknown option '--no-crunch'
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] Android Asset Packaging Tool
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] Usage:
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt l[ist] [-v] [-a] file.{zip,jar,apk}
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    List contents of Zip-compatible archive.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt d[ump] [--values] WHAT file.{apk} [asset [asset ...]]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    badging          Print the label and icon for the app declared in APK.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    permissions      Print the permissions from the APK.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    resources        Print the resource table from the APK.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    configurations   Print the configurations in the APK.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    xmltree          Print the compiled xmls in the given assets.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    xmlstrings       Print the strings of the given compiled xml assets.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt p[ackage] [-d][-f][-m][-u][-v][-x][-z][-M AndroidManifest.xml] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [-0 extension [-0 extension ...]] [-g tolerance] [-j jarfile] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--debug-mode] [--min-sdk-version VAL] [--target-sdk-version VAL] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--app-version VAL] [--app-version-name TEXT] [--custom-package VAL] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--rename-manifest-package PACKAGE] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--rename-instrumentation-target-package PACKAGE] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--utf16] [--auto-add-overlay] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--max-res-version VAL] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [-I base-package [-I base-package ...]] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [-A asset-source-dir]  [-G class-list-file] [-P public-definitions-file] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [-S resource-sources [-S resource-sources ...]]         [-F apk-file] [-J R-file-dir] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [--product product1,product2,...] \
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]         [raw-files-dir [raw-files-dir] ...]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    Package the android resources.  It will read assets and resources that are
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    supplied with the -M -A -S or raw-files-dir arguments.  The -J -P -F and -R
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    options control which files are output.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt r[emove] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    Delete specified files from Zip-compatible archive.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt a[dd] [-v] file.{zip,jar,apk} file1 [file2 ...]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    Add specified files to Zip-compatible archive.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  aapt v[ersion]
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    Print program version.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens] 
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]  Modifiers:
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -a  print Android-specific data (resources, manifest) when listing
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -c  specify which configurations to include.  The default is all
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        configurations.  The value of the parameter should be a comma
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        separated list of configuration values.  Locales should be specified
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        as either a language or language-region pair.  Some examples:
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]             en
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]             port,en
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]             port,land,en_US
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        If you put the special locale, zz_ZZ on the list, it will perform
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        pseudolocalization on the default locale, modifying all of the
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        strings so you can look for strings that missed the
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        internationalization process.  For example:
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]             port,land,zz_ZZ
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -d  one or more device assets to include, separated by commas
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -f  force overwrite of existing files
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -g  specify a pixel tolerance to force images to grayscale, default 0
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -j  specify a jar or zip file containing classes to include
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -k  junk path of file(s) added
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -m  make package directories under location specified by -J
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -u  update existing packages (add new, replace older, remove deleted files)
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -v  verbose output
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -x  create extending (non-application) resource IDs
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -z  require localization of resource attributes marked with
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        localization="suggested"
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -A  additional directory in which to find raw asset files
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -G  A file to output proguard options into.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -F  specify the apk file to output
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -I  add an existing package to base include set
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -J  specify where to output R.java resource constant definitions
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -M  specify full path to AndroidManifest.xml to include in zip
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -P  specify where to output public resource definitions
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -S  directory in which to find resources.  Multiple directories will be scanned
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        and the first match found (left to right) will take precedence.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    -0  specifies an additional extension for which such files will not
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        be stored compressed in the .apk.  An empty string means to not
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        compress any files at all.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --debug-mode
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:debuggable="true" in to the application node of the
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        manifest, making the application debuggable even on production devices.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --min-sdk-version
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:minSdkVersion in to manifest.  If the version is 7 or
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        higher, the default encoding for resources will be in UTF-8.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --target-sdk-version
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:targetSdkVersion in to manifest.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --max-res-version
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        ignores versioned resource directories above the given value.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --values
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        when used with "dump resources" also includes resource values.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --version-code
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:versionCode in to manifest.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --version-name
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        inserts android:versionName in to manifest.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --custom-package
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        generates R.java into a different package.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --auto-add-overlay
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        Automatically add resources that are only in overlays.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --rename-manifest-package
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        Rewrite the manifest so that its package name is the package name
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        given here.  Relative class names (for example .Foo) will be
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        changed to absolute names with the old package so that the code
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        does not need to change.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --rename-instrumentation-target-package
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        Rewrite the manifest so that all of its instrumentation
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        components target the given package.  Useful when used in
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        conjunction with --rename-manifest-package to fix tests against
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        a package that has been renamed.
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --product
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        Specifies which variant to choose for strings that have
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        product variants
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]    --utf16
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        changes default encoding for resources to UTF-16.  Only useful when API
[2012-01-30 22:37:10 - Buddha Athens]        level is set to 7 or higher where the default encoding is UTF-8.
```

Comment: search "android crunch" in the search bar above before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you updated the ADT plugin for Eclipse, but you are still using an older version of the Android SDK. Update the SDK tools and platform tools via the SDK Manager, and this problem should go away.

Comment: Thnx for help ....But Cant Run app..Bacause R.java not generated...I have link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html ...And download windows-->(android-sdk_r16-windows.zip) Now i extraxt it and give android sdk path to sdkManager ,Its right???